# Как закрасить часть Button?

Tags: android-sdk, android

В drawable файле я прописываю закрашивание кнопки белым цветом. Как прописать, чтобы она закрасилась на половину белым и на половину серым (в пассивном состоянии)? Вот имеющийся сейчас код:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>`

Я знаю, что можно назначит иконку, но мне нужно прописать это программно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В папке `res/drawable` создайте `xml` подобного вида, с названием, например, `test`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@android:color/black"
        android:startColor="@android:color/white" />

   </shape>
   ```
2. Назначьте его нужному состоянию селектора:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       ...
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/test" />
   </selector>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо! А можно как-то закрасить четверть? Или даже частично закрасить кнопку на которой стоит иконка?

Comment: Думаю да, но точно не скажу. Поэксперементируйте с `gradient` - может их можно несколько в одном `shape` разместить.

Comment: Сначала я прочитаю, что такое ``shape``, потом что такое ``gradient``, а потом буду экспериментировать.. :D

Comment: @bukashka101, верным путём идёте, товарищ)

Comment: Как только сделаю программную составляющую приложения, перейду к оформлению... Выдвигающиеся списки с кнопками и тд. Чувствую Вы подниметесь балов так на 1000 репутации :D.

Comment: Чего-то не закрашивается :(. Ну... Закрашивается сразу вся кнопка.